# Function definition with no parameter is called with a parameter. Why does this compile?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm surprised this compiles and runs. Why does it run? Also, the call return nothing even though the linq statement says there's a record.

Function's only definition (no overloads):

```
Public Function GetAlerts() As IEnumerable(Of Alert)
    Return (From a As Alert In NSOERContext.Alerts).ToList
End Function
```

Call to function:

```
Repo.GetAlerts(Me.ID) 'ID is an integer
```

Let me know if more data is needed. I'm running it in VS 2015.

Comment: Turn `OptionStrict` on... it wont compile.

Comment: Even with `Option Strict Off` it won't compile.

Comment: Unknown what this `Repo` object is.  Perhaps The `GetAlerts` that we see here is not defined on the Repo type.. or perhaps there is a GetAlerts overload that accepts an integer parameter.  It's impossible to tell from this distance.   *Your best bet is to set a breakpoint and step through your code*.

Comment: Your return statement does not match the return definition on the function - `IEnumerable(Of Alert) <> List(Of Alert)`